# Fragment error occurs while including a particular java file in Manifest

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

My app get stops while including particular java class in manifest.xml and the logcat shows error in fragment.If i remove those classes from manifest.xml the app is running successfully.On the other side remaining java classes working properly and there is no error in the fragment.I don't know why the app gets stopped for the particular java files

This is the error shown by logcat while including that particular java class

```
10-05 10:46:31.617  12820-12820/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4864)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob" on path: /system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner-1.apk
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4864)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:686)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:350)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1930)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-05 10:46:40.273  12820-12824/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 413K, 28% free 6025K/8348K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 36ms
```

front.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adview153613"
        android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragadmob" />

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/fron"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="50px"
                 android:background="#003399"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="iWedPlanner"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="600dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                 android:src="@drawable/ilogo" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Welcome to iWedPlanner"
                 android:textColor="#FF9933"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:textStyle="italic"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Your Guide to fun and flawless wedding planning"
                 android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
                 android:textStyle="italic"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/click"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                 android:background="#FFFFFF"
                 android:src="@drawable/ib" />

         </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragadmob.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/adview153613"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2" >

    <ImageView        
              android:id="@+id/image123"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"                    
              android:src="@drawable/adview1536132" />

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
         />
       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/addviewimage1"
          android:layout_width="31dp"
          android:layout_height="31dp"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
          android:src="@drawable/close" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

frontpage.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.bugsense.trace.BugSenseHandler;

public class Frontpage extends FragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       // The rest of your onStart() code.

        // //  EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.

      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.

        // EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
      }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, "68640bea");
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.front);


      RelativeLayout clic =(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.fron);
       clic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            //@Override
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(Frontpage.this,welcomeuser1.class);
                //Intent intent=new Intent(Frontpage.this,ZXingJarDemoActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }



    });



    }

    }
```

fragadmob.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class Fragadmob extends Fragment  {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragadmob, container,   false);

        //Admob        
         RelativeLayout gonad=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adview153613);
         ImageView addviewimage=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image123);
         ImageView inap=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addviewimage1);

         //   AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
           AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
          adView.loadAd(adRequest);



          if(addviewimage.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
             addviewimage.getLayoutParams().height = 30;
                // code to do for Portrait Mode
            }

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

Comment: something wrong in your layout xml Line # 9 . Post your xml also

Comment: somehting is wring in your layour xml. Post code for your am and for class com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage

Comment: @vimal kumar R : I think dependency for `com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView` is not resolved..!!

Comment: @ Ra Sharma it is resolved and other java classes working properly.Only for particular java class the app get stops.Don't know how to solve it

Comment: *com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob* does not exists. Can you confirm this is the right name of the fragment?

Comment: Can you provide the *Fragadmob* fragment aswell, with imports?

Comment: @Marko yes i have posted it

Comment: Kindly post this layout `R.layout.fragadmob`!

Comment: i posted it above @ Muhammad Babar

Answer (score 0):

You never need to add fragments to your manifest. your logcat showing `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob"` but Fragadmob extends Fragment so u trying to adding fragment in manifast so make sure once and enjoy coding.